# Ordering list of strings that contains a combination of int and int with characters

Tags: c#

I need to `Sort` a `List` in c# that has data like

```
{"301","301b","301a","300",302}
```

Expected output

```
{"300","301","301a","301b",302}
```

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Actually we expect at least a little effort from you to solve your problem. This is not a code writing service where you dump your requirements and others do your work. For the future, please provide some code that shows how you tried to tackle the problem, also describe what problem you have encountered with your code, and then we can help you to solve this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Natural Sort Order in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below one is your expected answer to make list in order.

```
List<string> abc=new List<string>() {"301","301b","301a","300","302"};
        
Console.WriteLine("Hello World {0}",string.Join("|",abc.OrderBy(x=>x).ToList()));
```

[working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OCrrix)